# Enclose Groups of the Same XML Tags With Beginning and Closing Tags

Tags: xml, insert, tags

How can I insert ending and closing tags around a group of the same xml tags within an XML document?  For instance, if my original XML looks as follows:

```
<recordImport OperatorID="ABC123">
     <patients>
        <patient roomNo=1 name="George Washington" addressID="1">
            <address ID="1" street="123 Credibility Street" city="Boston" state="MA"/>
            <address ID="1" street="456 Aqualung Avenue" city="Seattle" state="WA"/>
        </patient>
        <patient roomNo=2 name="Thomas Jefferson" addressID="2">
            <address ID="2" street="5 Famous Street" city="Burbank" state="CA"/>
        </patient>
     </patients>
 </recordImport>
```

How could I insert "addresses" tags as follows:

```
<recordImport OperatorID="ABC123">
    <patients>
        <patient roomNo=1 name="George Washington" addressID="1">
           <addresses>
              <address ID="1" street="123 Credibility Street" city="Boston" state="MA"/>
              <address ID="1" street="456 Aqualung Avenue" city="Seattle" state="WA"/>
           </addresses>
        </patient>
        <patient roomNo=2 name="Thomas Jefferson" addressID="2">
            <addresses>
              <address ID="2" street="5 Famous Street" city="Burbank" state="CA"/>
            </addresses>              
        </patient>
    </patients>
</recordImport>
```

I'd prefer a non-LINQ solution but I would use it if it came down to it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: which scripting language are you working on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular example you only have to include an `<addresses>` element as a child of every `<patient>`, which is trivial using XSLT. Presumably the general case is more complex.

With XSLT 2.0 a general solution is:

```
<xsl:template match="*[address]">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="node-name()">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="self::address">
         <addresses><xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/></addresses>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

combined with an identity template to copy other stuff unchanged.